# I cant get response from json encode

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to get values from form with serialize function and I correctly post and save to database but after this step my codes don't work . Someone help please ?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#kform").submit(function() {
         var data = $(this).serialize();

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "yenikayit2.php",
           data: data,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data) {
             if (data.tip === "dosya") {
               alert("tralalala d");
             }
             if (data.tip === "tercume") {
               alert("tralalala t");
             }
             if (data.tip === "hata") {
               alert("tralalala hata");
             }
           }



         });


       });
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

if($musteri_ekle) { //mysql control function
$musteri_id=mysqli_insert_id($baglanti);
$_SESSION[ 'musteri_id']=$musteri_id;
if ($secilen=="dosya" ) 
{ echo json_encode(array( "tip"=>"dosya")); }
else if ($secilen == "tercume") 
{ echo json_encode(array("tip"=>"tercume")); } }
else { echo json_encode(array("tip"=>"hata")); } ?>
```

Comment: "Don't work" doesn't give us much to go on. Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: I tried the PHP code with some modifications, it returns data alright. http://viper-7.com/n9hPpB

Comment: Code looks fine, just insure that url is correct, you can use any tool like firebug to detect that ajax request is hiting right url or not.

Comment: Can you please check the what the *yenikayit2.php* outputs. Use developer tools to find the response.

Comment: when i click the submit button, just page reloading and windows href return to my json data.

Comment: @ash_8247  the second code snippet is  yenikayit2.php

Comment: Did you check using e.preventDefault(); as *michael* Mentioned in his answer

Comment: @AniketSingh thank you , i will use and check it my code again

Answer (score 1):

Modify yenikayit2.php to avoid PHP fatal error and notices. You can either use `error_reporting(null);`
or edit the code as below

```
if (isset($musteri_ekle)) { // to avoid undefined variable error
    $musteri_id = mysqli_insert_id($baglanti);
    $_SESSION['musteri_id'] = $musteri_id;
    if ($secilen == "dosya") {
        echo json_encode(array("tip" => "dosya"));
    } else if ($secilen == "tercume") {
        echo json_encode(array("tip" => "tercume"));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("tip" => "hata"));
}
```

Comment: thanks but my problem is not about that,ı tried and nothing has change

Answer (score 0):

Well, i realized that i forgot put this fields on form action="" and method=""

after this i changed my jquery code :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
$("#kayit").click(function(event) { var data=$("#kform").serialize(); }
```

And this works correctly

Comment: What kind of a website is yours?

Comment: it is like automation @AltayMazlum

Comment: Attached to some other website?